# How to calculate pass % in both subjects given student failing %

Tags: percentages

Problem:

> In an Examination,35% fail in maths and 25% fail in English.If 10% fail in both the subjects.Then how much % pass in both?

Solution:

I applied the formula:

P(M)=Percentage of people fail in maths=35%.

P(E)=Percentage of people fail in english=25%.

P(M U E)=Percentage of people fail in in maths or english.
P(M U E)=P(M)+P(E)-P(M intersection E)

35%+25%-10%=50% fail in either of the subjects.

> But I am unable to calculate how to calc pass % in both subjects?
>
> Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

De Morgan's law is
$$\mathrm{not}(A\ \mathrm{or}\ B)=(\mathrm{not}\ A)\ \mathrm{and}\ (\mathrm{not}\ B)$$
So if they don't (fail math or fail English) then...

Comment: Not Understood Can you explain more clearly

Comment: @Jalaj I'm not sure if I can. Is there any specific thing that needs clarification?

Comment: @MattSamuel "pass both" means "not fail a and not fail be"

Comment: @Stella Yes, which is the negation of "fail a or fail b,."

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes. And you can't see how to answer the question from here?

Comment: @Stella Not sure you realize but I'm actually the answerer! I have a PhD in math, this is only slightly challenging for me :)

Comment: @MattSamuel Oh whoops, confused you and the OP.

Comment: @JalajChawla see above comments.